# Word for unquestioning belief/opinion.... Doctrine? Ideology?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

What is the word when someone considers any questioning of their view to be a moral failing or blindness of the questioner?

I'm thinking of a bottom up, community driven acceptance of a view or analytical model. I can think of a few examples in the current public conversation but I don't want to name them for fear of politicising the question.

'Dogma' may just be the word, but perhaps'dogma' suggests a 'Truth' mandated by locus of power rather than the crowd wisdom I have in mind. An example of dogma would be the biblical creation story where it is held to be true through reverence for its source.

Comment: We need to necessarily include the question in the body. Mention in the title is not enough.

Comment: 'Dogma[tism], fanaticism etc are given at the cited and other duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you might want -

## Dogma

> : a principle or set of principles laid down by an authority as
> [incontrovertibly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incontrovertible) true.
>
> *"The dogmas of faith"*

([From Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/dogma))

Comment: I'm thinking more of a bottom up, community driven acceptance of a view or analytical model. I am thinking of a few examples in the current public conversation but I don't want to name them for fear of politicising the question. 'Dogma' may be just the word, but the definition you've given suggests a 'Truth' mandated by power rather than the crowd wisdom  I have in mind.

Comment: @StephenBoston - Please edit that into the question.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Good suggestion.

Comment: I would say that "dogma" can easlitly be used for "bottom-up, community-driven" ideas to which that community no longer accepts contrary input.

Answer (score 1):

The word ***zealot*** comes to mind.

Zealot - a person who is fanatical and uncompromising in pursuit of their religious, political, or other ideals.

Answer (score -1):

A real life example would help, anyway I’d say that the behavior you are referring to is often defined as:

***[Fanaticism:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/inglese/fanaticism)***

> (disapproving) extreme beliefs that may lead to unreasonable or violent behaviour.

(Cambridge Dictionary)